# Скрипт с jQuery работает в Trampermonkey, но не работает без него

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

Добрый день.
Есть один скрипт, он создаёт объект span с текстом "0", и добавляет к этому span функцию onclick, которую я нашёл в коде сайта. Эта функция, как я понимаю, отправляет текст span, балл, который можно поставить комментарию.
Скрипт работает если его запускает Trampermonkey. Однако, если его сохранить как *.js и установить в google chrome без участия trampermonkey, он создаёт span, но при нажатии на созданный span выдаёт ошибку:

script.js:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: **$ is not defined**
    at HTMLSpanElement.LetsZeroGo.span.onclick (script.js:23)

По всей видимости не работает jQuery. Пробовал вызывать с задержкой, убирал @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js  ,ставил unsafeWindow, вызывал функцию с секундной задержкой. Итог один, в расширении скрипт работает, а сам по себе, отдельно - нет. В чём может быть причина этого?

```
// @name         addzero
// @namespace    kavicom.ru
// @version      1.0
// @description  addzero
// @author       you
// @include      http://www.kavicom.ru/*

// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

// @grant unsafeWindow

// ==/UserScript==

function LetsZeroGo() {
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("vote-numbers plus");
    for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++) 
    {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent="0"; // вот  нолик.

        span.onclick = function (){
            var div=$(".estim").has(this);
            div.html("подождите...");
            var link=$(this).parent(".vote-numbers").parent(".vote").find("a");
            var number=$(this).html();
            $.getJSON("/partners/vote/"+ link.attr("href")+'/'+ **number**,function(data){
                if(!data.error&&data.subtract_user_points){
                    user.has_points=user.has_points;
                }
                div.html(data.message);
            });
        };
        spans[i].insertBefore(span, spans[i].firstChild); 
    }
}
LetsZeroGo();
```

Comment: jQuery не загружен в страницу. Разбирайтесь почему.

Comment: @require это функционал teampermonkey. Для JS это просто комментарий в коде.

Comment: Я удаляю это // @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js И всё равно в trampermonkey работает, а без него - нет. Получается, что в трампере jQ подхватывается (загружается) с сайта, а если скрипт запускать не из трампера, то выдаёт ошибку.